# How to Create Calendar View For Hr Attendance in Odoo

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-14, odoo-15, odoo-16

Wanted to add calendar view for Hr.attendance in Odoo for version 16.0

Don't know how to create calendar view for hr.attendance. by default Odoo base doesn't provide calendar view for hr attendance and if we add calendar view type in action view type it shows us error like not having enough fields to create calendar view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a module which was very useful to me so I thought to share that module link with you all. After installing this module we can see calendar view for hr.attendance Odoo.

Plus Point: this module is available in **Version 14, 15 and 16 for FREE**.

LINK: https://apps.odoo.com/apps/modules/16.0/leafbyte_hr_attendance_calendar_view/

You all are probability thinking that if I know the answer then why I asked the Question in first place. So when I was searching for "How to Create Calendar View For Hr Attendance in Odoo" I noticed that nobody has asked this question on **Stack overflow** that's the reason I think to first create a Question and then provide a solution for it ;).